# Spring and Soap API error: "Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider"

Tags: java, spring, soap, paypal

I had a Spring based java app that connected to PayPal using their Soap API. It was working fine with Jetty, but when I tried to deploy it with Tomcat, I got the following error:

> Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider...

How can I solve this problem? I tried updating to the latest xerces jar files, as the error suggested, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve it, I had to add the following command line arguments to my JVM:

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

This can be done in Eclipse by

- double clicking on "Tomcat" in your "Servers" view
- choosing "Open launch configuration"
- select "Arguments" then "VM Arguments", and paste in the above 2 lines

Comment: Do you know any other way to solve the problem? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: i never came across another solution... this is still what I'm using myself!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively add the xerces.jar , xalan.jat and xml-apis.jar to your classpath